# Cyclic dependency of constraints: "Track To" to child object

Tags: constraints, parent

I have a cube and an empty which is the child of the cube. I add the "track to" constraint to the cube; the tracking target is the empty.

This will not work. When moving the cube, the empty will not move. I would like to have such a setup because it would be very intuitive for some animation nodes I am doing.

The console shows that I created a cyclic dependency of the constraints:

> Dependency cycle detected:
>
> Cube depends on Empty through Track To.
>   Empty depends on Cube through Parent.

I'd like to be able to move the cube (and the child - the empty - with it). Only when I explicitly move the empty, the cube should reorient itself in order to track the empty.

[image]

[image]

Any help or workaround is greatly appreciated.
blackno666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because a dependency cycle, i.e. both objects are dependent upon each other. To solve this, add another empty and parent both objects to it. To move the cube, move the parent empty.

Comment: When using blender --enable-new-depsgraph, the cyclic dependency can somewhat be broken if the "child of" constraint is used and only the "Location" is marked. Most of the time this will work, sometimes the cube's rotation will be off. Probably a bug in the new depsgraph.